# Firebase Functions v1 -> v2 Missing or Insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have two identical (ish?) functions going from v1 to v2.

The v1 function works.  The v2 function gives me:

```
{
  "code": 7,
  "details": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
  "metadata": {}
}
```

when I hit it with postman.  I've tried it with and without CORS set to true.  I've tried it using getFirestore() instead of admin.firestore().

What am I missing?  There is a Firestore rule on that collection, but I've disabled the rule for testing and no changes.

Thanks!

index.js:

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
initializeApp();
...
...
exports.testing = require('./testing');
```

testing.js:

```
const admin  = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

exports.v1 = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
     const uid = req.query.uid;
     
     try {
      const profileRef = admin.firestore().collection('profiles').doc(uid);
      const profileDoc = await profileRef.get();
      const profile = profileDoc.data();
      const name = profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName;
      res.send(name);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  }
);

exports.v2 = onRequest(async (req,res) => {
    const uid = req.query.uid;

    try {
      const profileRef = admin.firestore().collection('profiles').doc(uid);
      const profileDoc = await profileRef.get();
      const profile = profileDoc.data();
      const name = profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName;
      res.send(name);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I don't see any calls to `initializeApp` here for the admin SDK, has the Admin SDK been properly initialized elsewhere with its service account? For cloud functions, calling `initializeApp()` without arguments will pull the details it needs from the environment variables. If testing locally with the emulator, have you tried logging in and out of the `firebase` command line tool recently?

Comment: This is not the index.js, it's a separate ncluded file.  The V1 function works just fine. I'll update the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Based on [`firebase-functions` #1425](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1425) it seems to be related to an issue that affects a handful of users. The thread advises to raise a [support ticket](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) so the engineering team can take a look at it. In the request, link to the GitHub issue and this question. If you are advised of something useful, you should report it to both threads for the benefit of others who get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down. I've submitted a support request.